# jquery on and using jquery complex selectors

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, internet-explorer-7

I have this selector:

I have anchors around the page that start with a slash like this

```
<a href="/projects/case-study/">Link to case study</a>
```

And I also have this to stop them from working.

```
$("body").on("click", "a[href^='/']", function(e){
   return false;
});
```

This works find in all modern browsers and in IE10, 9, 8 but not 7.

Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Should probably use `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.preventDefault()` instead - these have been normalized across most browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you [(Mis?)using return false](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/).Following tasks are performes when we call `return false`:

1. event.preventDefault();
2. event.stopPropagation();
3. Stops callback execution and returns immediately when called.

The only action needed to cancel the default behaviour is `preventDefault()`.

```
   e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
```

So , you might end up as below:

```
$("body").on("click", "a[href^='/']", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```